# Calculating complex derivative from definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to check differentiability of $f(z)=\mathbb{Re}^3z+\mathbb{Im}^3z$ at $0$.

$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x+iy)-f(0)}{x+iy}$$

$$0\le|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x+iy}|\le \frac{|x^3|}{|x+iy|}+\frac{|y^3|}{|x+iy|}\le\frac{|x^3|}{|x|}+\frac{|y^3|}{|y|} \rightarrow 0$$

So $f'(0)$ exsists and is equal to $0$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfect.

Depending what is your background, you could have used known differentiability of some classical functions.

Namely the one of $z \mapsto \Re(z)$, $z \mapsto \Im(z)$ both from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Of $x \mapsto x^n$ (for $n$ integer) from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and mention that $f$ can be written as a composition of those functions.

And the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Comment: But is really $\mathbb{Re}z$ complex differentiable?

Comment: Yes. $\Re$  is a linear function between finite dimensional spaces. Even better, it is a projection.

Comment: But I've heard than the only functions that is complex differentiable and takes only real values is a constant function...

Comment: That's another notion called holomorphy. Indeed an holomorphic function taking only real values is constant.

Comment: but isn't that holomorphic = C-differentiable ?